# Is there a way to check over a column range for a certain data?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, match

I have 2 workbooks,
Spreadsheet A has multiple sheets of the same form.

Spreadsheet B records contain cells from Spreadsheet A sheets into a single row per sheet (log).

The first column in Spreadsheet B contains hyperlinks of all sheets in Spreadsheet A. I need to check the hyperlinks column in Spread B as follows:
if hyperlink exist in column A, 
check for the next sheet in Spreadsheet A index++ 
else
record the new data in a row after the last row,,,,

my code used to have clear() function to start submission from scratch to Spreadsheet B, but it's not efficient, execution time wise.
I am trying to manipulate my current code to check manually on existing records and i++/submit new row based on this logic.

you can ignore all missing lines of code because i have it working, i just need the logic of the idea of doing this, since I am not advanced in Apps Script. Thanks in advance for your help.

---

**Spreadsheet A - Sheet1**
[image: SpreadsheetA-sheet1]

---

**Spreadsheet A - Sheet2**
[image: SpreadsheetA-sheet2]

---

**Spreadsheet B**

[image: Workbook B Log]

---

I want the if statement to run on the Sheet link column in Workbook B.... in case of adding Sheet #3 to Workbook A (picture 1&2), upon submission, I want to check on Sheet links in Workbook B log (because it's unique) if it exists, i++.... if doesn't exist, add 3rd record in log.

```
for(var index = 2; index < WBA.length; index++) 
  {
    var Sheet   = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/WBA ID/edit#gid=";
    var SID     = WBA[index].getSheetId();
    var SheetID = Sheet + SID;
    var Data    = WBB.getDataRange().getValues();

    for(var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++)
    {
      if(Data[i][1] == SheetID)
        i++

      else
      {

    var lastRow = WBB.getLastRow() + 1;

    var Sheets_ID   = new Array()

    Sheets_ID.push( [WBA[index].getSheetId()] )
           WBB.getRange(lastRow,1).setFormula('=hyperlink("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/WBA ID/edit#gid=' + Sheets_ID +'")');

    var PN_Source    = WBA[index].getRange(6,3,1,1).getValues();      //getRange(row number, column number, number of rows, number of columns)
    var SC_Source      = WBA[index].getRange(8,3,1,1).getValues();
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have example spreadsheets

Comment: @Cooper unfortunately it's a very confidential file, I can't share both sheets with anyone, thanks for taking the time to reply though:)

Comment: Make up example files then because at this point I'd love to help you but I don't understand what your trying to accomplish.

Comment: Take a look at what this person did to clarify his question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570448/copy-and-paste-the-data-from-sheet1-to-sheet2-and-then-delete-the-entered-data-w/58571877?noredirect=1#comment103476084_58571877

Comment: @Cooper I added 3 screenshots of an example and description below it to illustrate the idea better.. thank you for your enthusiasm to help:)

Comment: I left you some note in your question regarding the areas which are unclear to me.  Please note Google Sheets don't have workbooks they have Spreadsheets.  You can use that terminology with other people but when your talking to Google Apps Script Programs they prefer Spreadsheet because that's the way it is in the documentation.  Also could you label which image is Spreadsheet A and which is Spreadsheet B?

Comment: @Cooper thanks for the clarifications, I was confused myself :D
first 2 pictures are sheet 1 and sheet 2 from spreadsheet A
3rd picture is spreadsheet B...
to eliminate any confusion, the idea simply is, I am collecting data from same data ranges in all sheets and copying it from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B. every row in spreadsheet B represents data collected from a single sheet in spreadsheet A
now, I want my script to add new records only by checking on Sheet link column in spreadsheet B, if sheet link already exist, check next sheet
if it doesn't exist add its data to spreadsheet B

Comment: You say `The first column in Spreadsheet B contains hyperlinks of all sheets in Spreadsheet A` but that doesn't agree with your image of Spreadsheet B

Comment: What are the column and row designations for Spreadsheet A images?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function checkForLink() {
  var ssB=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ssB.getActiveSheet();
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,1,1,4);
  var vA1=rg1.getValues()[0];
  var hObj={};
  vA1.forEach(function(el,i){if(el){hObj[el]=i;}});
  var linkA=sh1.getRange(2,hObj['Sheet Link']+1,sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var ssA=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SSA ID');
  var shts=ssA.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(sh,i){
    var vA=sh.getRange(1,1,2,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var sObj={};
    vA[0].forEach(function(e,i){sObj[e]=i;});
    var shlink=Utilities.formatString('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/%s//edit#gid=%s',ssA.getId(),sh.getSheetId());
    if(linkA.indexOf(shlink)==-1) {
      sh1.appendRow([vA[1][sObj.date],vA[1][sObj.age],vA[1][sObj.name],shlink]);
    } 
  });
}
```